# Methods to get coordinates on Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have a button to show me a text with the coordinates of the center of the bounds. Like the example shown on [easybutton](https://github.com/cliffcloud/Leaflet.EasyButton)

```
L.easyButton('fa-crosshairs fa-lg', function(btn, map){
alert('coordinates:'map.getCenter().toString())
}).addTo(Map);
```

But it only works with getCenter, if I change to getSouthEast or any of the corners of the bounds it doesn't work.
What am I missing here?
According to the [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds) it's the very same.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It doesn't return anything, it doesn't open the alert box.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I need to add getBounds() so it'd be like

```
L.easyButton('fa-crosshairs fa-lg', function(btn, map){
alert('coordinates:'map.getBounds.getSouthEast().toString())
}).addTo(Map);
```